# Smallest Scrabble board with all letters in play

Tags: scrabble

Was just doing a mental exercise and thought I'd ask people with *actual* knowledge and expertise in the game's theory:

> **What is the "smallest" legal Scrabble board on which all letters have been played at least once?**

- "Smallest" is defined here as "smallest occupied tiles-squared area".
- The area is absolute: no credit for any empty spaces within the occupied area.
- A blank is *not* required to satisfy the solution.
- While not restricted from use, blanks do not count as "playing" their respective letter either.

(Other variations would be "fewest tiles in play", or even just "lowest total board score".)

---

*As always, I **did** run searches first—here and elsewhere—before posting this. But if I still missed an answer to this same question, please direct me there with my apologies. I'm also only an amateur Scrabble player, so if there are any "official" terms that I should have used in this post, please let me know.*

Comment: Does it have to be a square; or are rectangles allowed? If a square, then 36 would be a simple minimum baseline; and I wouldn’t be at all surprised if that were the actual answer.

Comment: Rectangles are fine. I'd also like to see solution boards if possible…

Comment: 6x6=36, 7x4=28, 9x3=27, 10x3=30. The question comes down to which have legal solutions. Specify dictionary (may be relevant). My gut feeling is 6x6, because that allows the most extra vowels, but it may not have a viable solution.

Comment: I suppose a script could just brute force the problem, but I thought maybe a solution (or solutions) were already known. As for Dictionary, I'm a complete amateur for that: whatever is generally used for US tournament play.

Comment: If you don't find a definitive answer, the folks at Puzzling would probably find this an interesting challenge

Comment: When you say "legal Scrabble board": are you just asking that the words in the final configuration are legal? Or do you require that it's possible to reach that final position via a sequence of legal Scrabble moves?

Comment: Sorry to be tardy with the response, but I was implying a configuration reachable via normal/legal gameplay.